# What is Eclipse .ecl file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I googled everywhere but I don't know that these .ecl files are for?  I saw them on each Eclipse project that I got. Is it safe to delete them?

Comment: Is it related to [Epsilon Comparison Language](http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/ecl/)? I don't have any `.ecl` files in my Eclipse installation and workspace.

Comment: Why do you want to delete them anyways?

Comment: Try opening them with notepad++ or FileAnalyzer, maybe the contents will give you a hint.